# How to add multiple layers from one dataframe in ggplot?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am still new at R.

I am struggling with adding multiple layers from two different columns of a dataframe. This is my script:

```
b <- rnorm(500, mean=300, sd=60)
c <- rnorm(500, mean=350, sd=15)
id <- rep(1:50, each=10)
visit <- rep(1:10, 50)
df <- data.frame(id, visit, b, c)
```

I want to create a graph with visit on the x-axis, and b and c in the y-axis.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=visit, y=b)) + 
  geom_jitter(color="blue") + 
  geom_jitter(y=c, color="red")
```

This doesn't work, however. I know this does work when I have two different dataframes and the same column name. Is this the only way for me to add both b and c to the graph? Or is there another way?

Comment: the last line should be `geom_jitter(aes(y=c), color="red")` you need to overwrite the aesthetics inherited from the top layer. PS no questions are stupid, coding is hard :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to add multiple layers from one dataplot is to specify the `aes` in each layer:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=visit, y=b), color="blue") + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=visit, y=c), color="red")
```

[image]

For your specific example, the most `tidy` way to do this is to do what @GGamba suggests and make a tidy dataframe that has color as a categorical variable.

Comment: you really only need to specify `aes()` for layers where you want to overwrite the top layer. no need to define `x` twice

Comment: True, but I find that more confusing. It's easier for me to keep track if each layer clearly says what it is rendering rather than splitting it up between multiple `aes` statements. That's just my opinion, though

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a couple of group you can override the `aes` in each `geom`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=visit,y=b)) + 
  geom_jitter(color="blue") + 
  geom_jitter(aes(y=c), color="red")
```

[image]

But if you need to generalize, the approach is to have a 'tidy' dataframe:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id, -visit) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_jitter(aes(visit, value, color = key))
```

[image]

#### Data:

```r
b <- rnorm(500,mean=300,sd=60)
c <- rnorm(500,mean=350,sd=15)
id <- rep(1:50,each=10)
visit <- rep(1:10,50)
df <- data.frame(id,visit,b,c)
```

Created on 2018-05-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).